# Trying to pull user email when they check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull an active user's email when they check a box. I wish to paste the active user's email in a separate column (adjacent currently, but the ability to be flexible would be nice). I have done this before in a different worksheet, but for some reason I cannot get it to work on this one. I can get it to paste a simple variable, or even the edit date, so I am thinking there must be something erroring out with the user specifically. I am on a work owned domain with company addresses, but so is the other sheet that is working. Anyway, here is what I have currently (amature, be gentle):

```js
function onEditAdded(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "New Hires") {
    var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn();
    if (col == 20) {
      var dateCell = aCell.offset(0,1);
      if (aCell.getValue() === true) {
        var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
          Logger.log(email);
        dateCell.setValue(email);
      } else {
        dateCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: aCell.getValue() === true are sure that getValue is returning a boolean value and not a string of "true"? Also I find it helpful when debugging to insert console.log("here") lines in the code so that you can see if the code is hitting a certain line. I think aCell.getValue() === true is always false. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it should run without issues.
You just need to add it as an [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

**Manually create installable trigger:**

- Open your Apps Script project.
- click Triggers alarm.
- At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
- Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
- Click Save.

[image]

```
function onEditAdded(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "New Hires") {
    var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn();
    if (col == 1) {
      var dateCell = aCell.offset(0,1);
      if (aCell.getValue() === true) {
        var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
          Logger.log(email);
        dateCell.setValue('user@example.com');
      } else {
        dateCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can also explore on how to create installable triggers programmatically, so that you wont need to add it manually every time you copy this script to a different workbook.

**References:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically

[Is there any way to automatically create installable triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499233/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-create-installable-triggers)

Comment: OMG I am so dumb! Thank you so much I thought I was going crazy. For real though, thank you!